# ANGULAR - Disable submit button if form value not changed

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

i have form for selected date. how to disable the submit button if nothing changed in date form?

my html code

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <label><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Start <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <input id="startTrip1" name="NgbDate" data-provide="datepicker" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [markDisabled]="markDisabled" [minDate]="minDates" type="text" class="form-control form-flat" [(ngModel)]="ad.start_date" (dateSelect)="onDateSelect($event, ad)" (blur)="validateInput()" (click)="d.toggle()" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [disabled]="form.controls.tripduration.hasError('required')" >
      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="(ad.start_date == '' || ad.start_date == undefined) && ngForm.submitted">
         * This field is required
       </div>
      <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="form.controls.tripduration.hasError('required')">
      * Fill the durations first
      </div>
 </div>
//submit button
<button class="col-xs-12 text-center text-strong pointer custom-trip-btn" (click)="publishTrip()">
<button class="custom-trip-btn">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Do you only want this when the page is loaded or also when the user changes a value from the original to something else and then back again?

Comment: when the user changes a value from the original to something else and then back again

Answer (score 12):

If you used below code, the button only enabled if user changed value in the form

```
[disabled]="!(accountForm.valid && accountForm.dirty)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>    

<button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.dirty">Submit</button>
```

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982790/how-to-check-for-changes-in-form-in-angular-2-using)

Comment: it work to disable the button. but when i try to edit the date, the button always disabled

Comment: then try [disabled]="!profileForm.dirty" or [readonly]="!profileForm.dirty" on the input

Comment: @SoniSilalahi Will you able to share your full form code?

Comment: <button type="submit" [disabled]="profileForm.pristine">Submit</button>
 Try  this instead of dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works!

```
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>    

<button [disabled]="!(profileForm.valid ||!profileForm['isDirty']())" 
class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

[Check some what same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933229/update-form-with-validation-not-working-until-atleast-one-value-is-changed-in-th/53943990#53943990)

[Stackblitz-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editform-egqagp) of some old problem of mine

for the above you need to use RxReactiveFormsModule [RxReactive npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators/v/1.1.2?activeTab=readme)